# How to remove nested array attribute

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have below Json payload and I want to remove **banNum** attribute alone(**inventory[]->services[]->accountDetails[]: banNum**) from given payload when **services**[] array **category** is **SL** and **available** is **true**, I am new for muleSoft and little confusing to achieve my requirement , Can some on help me to achieve requirement .

### **Json Payload**

```
{
  "inventory": [
   {
    "category": {
     "name": "inventory1",
     "services": [
      {
       "category": "FB",
       "serviceType": "FB",
       "available": false,
       "accountDetails": [
        {
         "banNum": "1111",
         "status": "A"
        }
       ]
      },
      {
       "category": "SL",
       "serviceType": "SL",
       "available": true,
       "accountDetails": [
        {
         "banNum": "12345",
         "status": "A",
         "inventor": true,
         "migration": false,
         "indicator": true
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   },
   {
    "category": {
     "name": "inventory2",
     "services": [
      {
       "category": "wireless",
       "desc": "wireless",
       "available": true
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

### **Expected Payload**

```
{
  "inventory": [
   {
    "category": {
     "name": "inventory1",
     "services": [
      {
       "category": "FB",
       "serviceType": "FB",
       "available": false,
       "accountDetails": [
        {
         "banNum": "1111",
         "status": "A"
        }
       ]
      },
      {
       "category": "SL",
       "serviceType": "SL",
       "available": true,
       "accountDetails": [
        {
         "status": "A",
         "inventor": true,
         "migration": false,
         "indicator": true
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   },
   {
    "category": {
     "name": "inventory2",
     "services": [
      {
       "category": "wireless",
       "desc": "wireless",
       "available": true
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dw::core::Values::update`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-values-functions-update) function to easily update nested structures.

Note for nested updates you need to pass the field's path as an array

```js
%dw 2.0
import update from dw::util::Values
output application/json
---
payload update ["inventory", "category", "services"] 
    with ((services) -> 
        services map ((service) -> 
            if(service.category != "SL") service
            else service update "accountDetails" 
                        with ((accountDetail) -> accountDetail map $ - "banNum")
        )   
    )
```